# quill component does not load saved comments

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a comment system using the quill component. The system is already saving, but I need to load the saved comments to have the option to edit them

HTML:`

```
 <div *ngIf="renderedEditor" class="col-12 md:col-12 pt-2">
                <p-editor formControlName="descricao" [style]="{ height: '160px'}"></p-editor>
            </div>`
```

TS:

```
  carregarAnotacoes() {
    this.renderedEditor = true;
    if (this.idAtividade != undefined) {
      this.anotacaoService
        .listarPorAtividade(this.idAtividade as number, this.exibirSistema)
        .subscribe({
          next: (anotacoes) => {
            this.anotacoes = [...this.anotacoesSalvar, ...anotacoes];
          },
          error: () => {
            this.exibirMsgError.emit(
              'Não foi possível carregar a(s) anotação(ões), tente novamente.'
            );
          },
        });
    }
  }
```

API JAVA:

```
    @Operation(summary = "Listar atividadeAnotacao", description = "Listar atividadeAnotacaos", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "Authorization"))
    @GetMapping(path = "listar")
    ResponseEntity<List<AtividadeAnotacao>> listar(
            @RequestParam(value = "pesquisa", defaultValue = "") String pesquisa);
```

Already tried:

I have already tried to load comment variables saved to an empty variable, but without success, the quill component does not load the description.

```
Ex:carregarComentarioParaEdicao() {this.comentarioEditado = this.comentarioSalvo;}
```